# Unable to push docker image on local private registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'am struggling with this problem. I have to push a docker image (which work rigthly with docker-compose up) to my local registry which was setup with the following command:

`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2`

This is the output of 'docker ps'

`5fe319f37d5c        registry:latest         "/entrypoint.sh /etc/"   41 hours ago Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp                                                   registry`

I follow the steps to push the image:

`docker-compose up --build`
`docker tag gatewayapi_api localhost:5000/gatewayapi_api`
`docker push localhost:5000/gatewayapi_api`

but in every case I obtain

`file integrity checksum failed for "etc/default/cacerts`

I try every solution (restart docker, clean image, restart registry)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

In [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33991) GitHub issue people are sharing their findings how to fix that issue.

TL;DR:

- On docker for Mac you might need to increase docker VM memory in the app Preferences->Advanced->Memory
- If did not help then cleanup might do it (helped me): `docker system prune -a`

Comment: it only worked for me once I pruned all images (including the one I was trying to push) and regenerated it.

Comment: the `prune` did the trick. But be aware that it will pretty much remove all your images and containers.

Comment: Thank god (Vasyl Boroviak) the reminder about docker system prune -a !

Answer (score 1):

Does your registry work correctly with an official image? Like this:

```
docker pull alpine
docker tag alpine localhost:5000/my-alpine
docker push localhost:5000/my-alpine
```

Comment: My local registry work correctly with an official image like 'ubuntu' (pull->tag->push to my registry->pull to my registry)

Comment: How about the image itself? Does `docker history gatewayapi_api` show all the layers you'd expect?

Comment: Command show me the layer list. In particular after 6th corret layer, the 7th say: "<missing>  2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c set -x  && apt-get update  && apt-   187.9 MB". After the 7th layer, all layer show as IMAGE entry the "<missing>" value. This 7th layer retry twice in push docker image. After that I obtain "file integrity checksum failed for "etc/default/cacerts". Seems to be a image build problem. It is right?

Comment: I'd say so. Try building the image explicitly with `docker build` rather than with Compose, and check the output.

Comment: 'docker-compose up' and 'docker build' produce the same problem with the same output when I launch 'docker history gatewayapi_api'

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04 with package docker.io. Would have error "file integrity checksum failed" when pushing image to my private docker registry. In my case the problem was fixed by following this official fix from Docker web site:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#your-kernel-does-not-support-cgroup-swap-limit-capabilities

Note that my Docker private registry was running as a container as above:

> docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2

I was building and pushing Docker images from the same Docker engine on the same Ubuntu 20.04 computer, communicating through the socket (not the ethernet).

I don't know if the problem was from the Docker client building the image or from the Docker private registry receiving the image, which was itself running as a container. In any case, following the above official fix was the only thing I needed to get the problem resolved, I changed nothing else.

1. Log into the Ubuntu or Debian host as a user with sudo privileges.
2. Edit the /etc/default/grub file. Add or edit the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line to add the following two key-value pairs:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"

3. Update GRUB. *If your GRUB configuration file has incorrect syntax, an error occurs. In this case, repeat steps 2 and 3.*

> $ sudo update-grub

4. The changes take effect when the system is rebooted.